# WriteProcessMemory in OOP approach

Tags: delphi, memory, patch

Writing in memory to replace a class (TMyEdit) by another (TEdit) at runtime

```
const
  vmtNewInstance = System.vmtNewInstance;

var
  AClassInstance: TClass;
  OldInstance: Pointer;

function GetNewInstance: TObject;
begin
  Result := AClassInstance.NewInstance;
end;

function GetVirtualMethod(AClass: TClass; const VmtOffset: Integer): Pointer;
begin
  Result := PPointer(Integer(AClass) + VmtOffset)^;
end;

procedure SetVirtualMethod(AClass: TClass; const VmtOffset: Integer; const Method: Pointer);
var
  WrittenBytes: DWORD;
  PatchAddress: PPointer;
begin
  PatchAddress := Pointer(Integer(AClass) + VmtOffset);
  WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess, PatchAddress, @Method, SizeOf(Method), WrittenBytes);
end;


initialization
  OldInstance := GetVirtualMethod(TMyEdit, vmtNewInstance);
  AClassInstance := TMyEdit;
  SetVirtualMethod(StdCtrls.TEdit, vmtNewInstance, @GetNewInstance);

finalization
  SetVirtualMethod(StdCtrls.TEdit, vmtNewInstance, OldInstance);
```

This works fine, but how to write OOP approach?
Here is my attempt:

```
type
  TVirtualMethod = class
      FInstance: Pointer;
      FTarget: TClass;
    public
      constructor Create(const SourceClass, DestClass: TClass);
      destructor Free;
  end;

{ TVirtualMethod }

var
  ASource: TClass;

function GetNewInstance: TObject;
begin
  Result := ASource.NewInstance;
end;

constructor TVirtualMethod.Create(const SourceClass, DestClass: TClass);
var
  WrittenBytes: DWORD;
  PatchAddress: PPointer;
begin
  ASource := SourceClass;
  FInstance := PPointer(Integer(ASource) + vmtNewInstance)^;
  FTarget := DestClass;
  PatchAddress := Pointer(Integer(DestClass) + vmtNewInstance);
  WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess, PatchAddress, @GetNewInstance, SizeOf(GetNewInstance), WrittenBytes);
end;

destructor TVirtualMethod.Free;
var
  WrittenBytes: DWORD;
  PatchAddress: PPointer;
begin
  PatchAddress := Pointer(Integer(FTarget) + vmtNewInstance);
  WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess, PatchAddress, @FInstance, SizeOf(FInstance), WrittenBytes);
end;

var
  v1: TVirtualMethod;

initialization
  v1 := TVirtualMethod.Create(TMyEdit, TEdit);

finalization
  v1.Free;
```

It compiles well, but it writes in memory away.

Comment: I wonder why you have to resort to such an approach. What's driving this design choice?

Comment: Dependency Injection, instant memory replace VCLs or something...

Comment: If you are in charge of the process then I think there will be easier solutions than this

Comment: Of course, we can simply redefine (TMyEdit=class(TEdit);), but we have to USES MyEdit.pas in all units. Memory class patch allows to do this one time and include the patcher only in the dpr file project, this is kind of removing dependencies.

Comment: Pretty cool, but how are you getting away with not using MyEdit.pas in all units before the patch?

Comment: There are hooks in the streaming framework that allow you to substitute your class for the standard VCL class.

Comment: @MarcusAdams, I couldn't before the patch.@David there is Spring framework for delphi that may be the best way to resolve dependencies: http://code.google.com/p/delphi-spring-framework/

Comment: There are MUCH easier ways to accomplish component replacements, with ugly hacks. Interceptor classes come to mind, for instance (define a class named 'TEdit', derived from the standard 'TEdit', in the same `TForm` unit and needs to use it - the compiler will substitute it automatically).

Comment: David Hefferman is right, the DFM streaming system has 2 hooks specifically for replacing components at runtime.

Comment: Any assumption regarding TMyEdit and TEdit class affiliation ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB using hooks? can you provide an example? using Interceptor classes works fine, but you still need to include USES, Interceptor on TApplication (then loop) may be the good one.

Comment: By hooks, I was referring to the `OnFindComponentClass` and `OnCreateComponent` events of the `TReader` class, which is used during DFM streaming. Either one of them can be used to substitute a `TMyEdit` object whereever a `TEdit` object is needed. As for interceptor classes, they can be written inline inside the `TForm` unit itself. You would only need to involve the `uses` clause if you implement the class in its own unit. Lastly, depending on what functionality you are actually trying to replace, a simpler `class helper` for the standard `TEdit` class might be a better choice.

Comment: @Kachwahed: You seems to take delight at doing some code injection. Head to [this](http://admon.free.fr/downloads/libs/lib_delphi/injection/injection.zip). Not the OOP way but really down to the metal.

Comment: @Kachwahed: Why not this [hack](http://sourcecodeadventures.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/hellishly-horrible-hack-1-changing-an-objects-functionality-without-recompiling/) of [Cobus Kruger](http://stackoverflow.com/users/127826/cobus-kruger).

Comment: @menjaraz thanks! sounds great, looks the same code in other ways, I'll try to OnFindComponentClass as legal way, actually I'am just looking for an easy way to replace components.

Answer (score 0):

[TVirtualMethodInterceptor](http://blog.barrkel.com/2010/09/virtual-method-interception.html) features appear to overlap some of your intents and do it in the OOP way.